# Exception has occurred: TypeError rmdir: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not TemporaryDirectory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

Please tell me what is the problem with this code?

**CODE:**

```
import tempfile
import os
temp_dir=tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
print("Directory name:", temp_dir)
os.removedirs(temp_dir)
```

**ERROR:**

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
rmdir: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not TemporaryDirectory
```

Answer (score 2):

`TemporaryDirectory` is an object, that is initially designed to be used in a context (`with` statement) to avoid having to take care of the deletion manually. It has a `cleanup` method that can be called manually to delete the temporary folder, and an attribute `name` that returns the full path of the directory. So you could either call `temp_dir.cleanup()` directly, or `os.removedirs(temp_dir.name)`.

If you really want to manage the lifetime of the folder by yourself, you should rather use `tempfile.mkdtemp`.

For more information, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223604/how-to-create-a-temporary-directory-and-get-the-path-file-name-in-python) another thread about this same topic. To wrap up, keep in mind that `TemporaryDirectory` has been designed to make your life easier and safer by deleting the temporary folder automatically for you behind the scene:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir_fullpath:
     # Beware temp_dir_fullpath != tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() !!!
     print('created temporary directory:', temp_dir_fullpath)
```

It is very convenient for short-living directory, restricted to a single context (namely not passing the path to other methods or classes...). However, if you need to manager it by yourself (mainly to reuse it later in different contexts or passing it to other methods), in my opinion you are better off doing the job by yourself and just using plain `tempfile.mkdtemp` method, which is what `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory` is probably doing under the hood, adding extra sugar for automatic deletion at the cost of returning an object instead of a plain string. This way it is clear that you are handling the deletion by yourself rather than a mistake.

Comment: If you can explain more about this to me Or in this case, introduce me to some cases of the site

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest ways to resolve the resolve the issue as [milemabar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4820605/milembar) mentioned, but may not be obvious at first glance, is to use this API:

```
temp_dir.name
```